# What is the color of Luke Skywalker's Hoth attire?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, luke-skywalker, clothing, battle-of-hoth

I am just curious of the color of his outfit during the Battle of Hoth. I am referring to the moment when he is mounted on his tauntaun, and when his body was upside in wampa's lair.

Comment: As usual, it would be helpful if DV'ers provided feedback on why the question warrants a DV in the comments.

Comment: Since the color is obviously a cream or beige color, I assume the OP is looking for the actual fabric dye, which would be a behind-the-scenes or production question...

Comment: I didn’t downvote, but I’d say its because this question is asking for a combination of getting a picture (which is easy), and naming a color.

Comment: I downvoted because the question (as written) is lacking in research effort. I voted to close because I'm pretty sure that the OP didn't mean what they've actually asked.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you call this:

[image: Close up of Luke astride his tauntaun looking out over the snowy landscape' he has his hood up and goggles on his head; the base uniform is white with a beige sleeveless jacket over the top]

Luke wears the same attire during his brief time as a popsicle in the wampa's lair.

Seems like beige, or very light brown. Color sampling with GIMP yielded no practical results.

Answer (score 2):

Luke is wearing an attractive ensemble consisting of the latest in RebelFashion™.

He's wearing a standard white Rebel shirt with grey Rebel trousers, grey Rebel snow boots, a saucy tan insulated Rebel jacket as well as a brown belt with an oversized lightsaber clip.

[image: Backstage photo of "Han", "Leia" and "Luke" in their Hoth costumes: Han looks to the floor, Leia smiles to the camera and Luke reaches over to lick Leia]

Comment: Given the later reveal about Luke & Leia, that picture is really creepy...

Comment: I hope the downvote is from someone who feels we shouldn't answer bad questions (because it validates the questions somehow), and not because they think people can't have a little fun while answering.